# Test with Springboot with @Transactional never ends

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I've converted my small application into Springboot. But the funny thing is, my JDBC transactional tests now fail with the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:252)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionContext.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:203)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:211)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:120)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:250)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:650)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:457)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:512)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:200)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:539)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:325)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:418)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:627)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:321)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:124)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:303)
    ... 41 more
```

This is the snippet of my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "classpath:/test.application.properties",
    classes = {DatasourceConfiguration.class})
@Transactional
public class BasicSanityIntegrationTest {
  @Test
  public void shouldBeOkay() {
    System.out.println("Check if transaction is visible in the log!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's my bad. The properties argument is not supposed to point to a properties file location. Probably for direct `key=value` pairs.

I changed into this and it works now.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {DatasourceConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@Transactional
public class BasicSanityIntegrationTest {
  @Test
  public void shouldBeOkay() {
    System.out.println("Check if transaction is visible in the log!");
  }
}
```